# What's the difference between `%` and `,` in python formatters?

Tags: python, escaping, formatter

Sometimes I see the use as such:

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"
print "%s, %s" %(a, b)
```

and sometimes like:

```
print "%s, %s", (a, b)
```

Is there a difference behind the scenes?

Comment: I prefer '{0}'.format(a)

Comment: The second example doesn't do the same thing as the first, so there's one obvious difference right there. Perhaps you're thinking of a different context than `print`? Maybe in the `logging` library, or database access, or something else?

Comment: the second code isn't python formatter. The first is a string formatter. It will build the new string as a parameter for the print function. On the second print, (a, b) is the second parameter of the function print

Answer (score 2):

They print different things:

```
>>> print "%s, %s" %(a, b)
foo, bar
>>> print "%s, %s", (a, b)
%s, %s ('foo', 'bar')
```

The first one uses the string `"%s, %s"` and uses the string formatting operator `%` to insert the values `a` and `b` into the format placeholders. That resulting string is then printed using the print statement.

The second one passes two things to the print statement: The string `"%s, %s"` and a tuple `(a, b)`. Both these things are independently printed, so no string formatting is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to begin using .format() instead.

ie: print('{} {}'.format(a, b)

Takes care of a lot of problems as well as not having to worry about string, decimal, etc.